# Pandas escribe nombre de campos al exportar CSV Python

Tags: python

Estoy programando un pequeño desarrollo, pero tengo problemas al escribir en un CSV no quiero que panda escriba el nombre de los campos, pero no he podido eliminar esta opción, leí la documentación y agregué el argumento "index_label=False" e "index=False" al exportar el archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
   import pandas as pd

    a=[1,2,3,4,5]
    b=[6,7,8,9,10]
    expHISTORIA=pd.DataFrame([a,b]).transpose() #crear DataFrame
    expHISTORIA.to_csv('Historias.csv',index=False,index_label=False, mode='a',sep=';') #crear el CSV
```

El problema es que el archivo generado contiene campos, yo quiero que no los imprima que solo genere el archivo con los datos.

Lo que imprime es lo siguiente:

```
   0    1
   1    6
   2    7
   3    8
   4    9
   5    10
```

Pero los primeros dos números son (0, 1) son campos que se crean automáticos y no quiero que estén. Lo ideal sería que imprima esto:

```
   1    6
   2    7
   3    8
   4    9
   5    10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto :

```
df.to_csv('your_array.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

header es un parámetro booleano en el que defines si quieres escribir o no las cabeceras del dataframe.

Comment: Claro de esa forma no lo imprime, pero sabes deja un vacío donde deberían ir los campos, o explicado de otra forma en vez de escribir en la fila 1 lo hace en la fila 2. Lo ideal es que escriba desde arriba

Comment: Omite lo anterior, está perfect!